# Splitting rails active record models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-responsibility-principle

I like the idea of keeping models tight and creating new classes or modules for specific logic (keeping in line with the single-responsibility principle).

From what I understand Active Record associations, scopes and validations all belong to an active record model within rails. However, sometimes these alone can make a model file quit large. Would splitting an active record model into sub models using `class_eval` pass the coding sniff test? See example below:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Associations
  include Validations
  include Scopes
end

# app/models/user/associations.rb
class User
  module Associations
   User.class_eval do
     # insert belongs_to, has_many, etc.
   end
  end
end

# app/models/user/scopes.rb
class User
  module Scopes
   User.class_eval do
     # insert scopes
   end
  end
end

# app/models/user/validations.rb
class User
  module Validations
   User.class_eval do
     # insert validations
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've moved associations, methods, and scopes out to modules, to keep SRP on those. But I kept it all relating to the same thing, it social media functionality; likes would have it's own module, etc. Not sure if it passes the smell test, but it's something I've done in prod

Comment: This is why [Concerns](https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/09/16/rails-concers-to-concern-or-not-to-concern.html) exist.